# Android Support Package Usage

Tags: android

I am having trouble using a class from the android-support-v4.jar when running on a 2.3.6 Razor.  I added the libs folder and placed this android-support-v4.jar jar file inside, yet when I deploy from Eclipse to the real phone, I get a ClassNotFoundException when the Notification.Builder... code is encountered.